# Can I run a Java Spring Batch program in JavaSE environment?

Tags: spring-batch, zos, jsr352, java-batch

We are exploring deployment/execution modes for the Java batch programs being created for z/OS (mainframe)

Option 1: Deploy it in Liberty profile

Option 2: Can I run Spring Batch program in a JavaSE environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There is no required dependency on an application server for Spring Batch.  In fact, using Spring Boot to generate an über jar and running it that way is the recommended approach for running Spring Batch jobs currently.

Comment: Is the execution of über jar approach possible in z/OS (mainframe) environment also ?

Comment: If you can start a JRE, you can run an über jar.